# How to set in-call volume

Tags: audio, volume-control

How can you set the in-call volume to be higher for Android 2.2, please?
In the Settings options there's only these options:

Incoming Call Volume (which I presume is the ringer volume)
Media Volume
System Volume (which would probably increase the in-call volume, but all the others as well)
Notification Volume

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From searching android forums I see that some people had screen protectors covering the speaker. Could this be your issue?

I also saw reference to the [Quick Settings](http://www.appbrain.com/app/quick-settings/com.bwx.bequick) app which has a Voice Call Volume setting. Hopefully you can set that to its highest setting and your calls will at least be set to the loudest setting.

Comment: Thanks, Gary. There's no screen protector. I gave forums a search as well before posting only to see some having sound too low and other having it too high... I'll give that app you're mentioning a look and come back. Thank you.

Comment: Hey. It's a really useful application, however it does what the side volume keys do. This probably means I must raise the Master level to get better spearker volume, which is something I would have wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 6):

During a call press the volume UP (+) button. You're bound by what levels the manufacturer allows for in the phone & any other law needed to be met within your country.

If you're technically inclined,

> Flash your phone with a kernel that
>   uses Pershoot audio booster (usually
>   OC/UV)

Comment: Thanks, Sparx. I had already tried the side volume keys, I'm not that 'amateurish', although the question does look like that at first glance.