# Reduce minimum in call volume

Tags: volume-control, calls

**I find that the minimum in-call volume on my HTC Desire is still far to loud on some calls.**

Since I got the phone, I have flashed several different custom ROMs, radio updates, etc, and have had the issue throughout.

**Do you know of any way (setting, hack, app, whatever) to reduce the minimum volume?**

My device is rooted and I am currently running one of the CyanogenMod 7 (Gingerbread) nightly builds.

Comment: P.S. I have tried asking my wife to speak more quietly but this did not help. Anything. At all. If you are having the same problem, do not try this.

Comment: Lol.  Have you tried holding the phone farther from your ear? :P

Comment: For what it's worth, this person has the opposite problem: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4113/how-to-set-in-call-volume

Comment: FWIW I tested the Scotch tape solution and it does the trick.

Comment: Asking wife to speak more quietly usually leads to the opposite result...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was reminded by a friend that the CyanogenMod ROM I am using includes 'DSPManager' which is essentially a graphic equaliser with profiles for Headset, Phone Speaker and Bluetooth Device.

By lowering all the levels for the Phone Speaker profile I have managed to reduce the minimum in call volume (hooray!).

For people using ROMs other than CM on a rooted device, I believe a combination of DSPManager APK and modified audio library can be flashed but [people appear to have had mixed results](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=772564).

Comment: Is this still the solution you use or have you found something more elegant and software based?

Answer (score 6):

[image]

1. Place a single layer over the speaker.*
2. Repeat Step 1 as needed.

**Works with Wii-motes too.*

Comment: Upvoted for using hardware to help solve what I originally thought to be a software issue!

Comment: I was going to suggest duct tape but I doubt @FoleyIsGood's wife talks _that_ loud. ;)

Comment: Thanks, have upvoted and will keep as a backup plan, but was definitely looking for a software solution!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You actually have to turn it up.....then turn it down. Doesn't make sense, but it is working.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/) can do this.  I've seen references to people doing it, but I haven't found a specific profile/recipe for it.  They have a 7-day trial you can get to fool around with it.

Comment: I use Tasker and there are lots of ways you can set the in call volume but only within the standard levels.