# Loud Ringer Volume with Incoming Calls?

Tags: audio, calls, volume-control

When I listen to Spotify, I all the time modify the lound-speaker button on the side but it is irritating when someone calls and the Ringer Volume is low so cannot hear it. Is it possible to set the Ringer Volume high so that Spotify or accidental side-bar -button pressing does not distrupt the listening and incoming calls?

**Method 1:** *In contacts, one can specify Ring Tune but I would like more advanced settings, perhaps configured in Desktop -- possible?*

> **My Phone**
>
> ```
> Phone Model: U8800 (Huawei)
> Android version: 2.3.5
> Baseband v: 404020
> Kernel v: 2.6.35.7-perf
> ```
>
> **Perhaps related**
>
> 1. [How to set in-call volume](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4113/how-to-set-in-call-volume)

Comment: What device/OS are you using? The ringer volume and media volume are generally separate values.

Comment: @AlEverett: updated the info to the q.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize an app like [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) for this. *Tasker* is an automation tool, which executes configured tasks on configured associated events, which can be time-based, location-based, state-based, and event-based. So you can trigger the execution of a certain task at a given time, or when you reach a certain location, when an SMS arrives (event), a specific person calls you (event), or -- now it comes -- a certain app is running in foreground (state).

So basically, to get back to your question, you could advise *Tasker:* "When I'm running Spotify in the foreground, adjust ringer volume to maximum."

As a side-effect, you could also do things like "When I run maps, activate GPS"; "When I reach the office, adjust ringer, notification, etc" (to not annoy your co-workers -- does a great job for me); "When I come home, activate Wifi", and much more. Oh, even such easy things like "When I place my phone face-down: SHUT UP! All volumes to Zero! DO NOT DISTURB!" :-)

So to sum up, it's the final swiss army knife for Android...